# "No module named 'pip.commands'; 'pip' is not a package" when running pip

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

```
C:\Users\magnaboy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>pip install praw

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\magnaboy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", l
ine 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\magnaboy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", l
ine 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\magnaboy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe\
__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\magnaboy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\pip.py", lin
e 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\magnaboy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\pip.py", lin
e 83, in bootstrap
    from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand
ImportError: No module named 'pip.commands'; 'pip' is not a package
```

I've followed several tutorials with exact instructions and pip isn't working no matter what I do. I am on Windows 7 trying to install PIP on the latest version of Python. Any idea what I can do to fix this? All the tutorials I can find are outdated and dont provide a lot of information.

Comment: Notice that it says `'pip' is not a package`. You have a "pip.py" module in in your "Python35\Lib" directory. It doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

[@eryksun is right](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun), you haven't installed `pip` correctly, and there shouldn't normally be any `pip.py` in `Lib`.

It looks like [the PIP bootstrap script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) (I dunno what it's doing or how it got there): [that script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) does have `from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand` on line `83` in a function named `bootstrap`.

So, either

- delete it and run [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html), or
- move it out of Python installation and run it as a standalone script as per [its docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py).